# Two same directives on one controler, dom load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

Hello i have controler template, in which i declared two directives that are used for banners. 
so i have home.html
and

```
<div data-banner="{typeName: '1'}">
<div data-banner="{typeName: '2'}">
```

and

```
function bannerDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'banner/banner.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: bannerController,
        scope: {
            bannerOptions: '=banner'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('bannerOptions', function() {
                $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                    loop: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    pagination: false,
                    items: 1
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And i need to use `$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel` on both of those directives to display with route change both banners. And i dont have a clue how to make it work.

Comment: `link` passes an element.

Comment: In controler there is method to get banners from server.

Comment: There are also modules available for this   see https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel. Check for modules before you re-invent the wheel

Comment: and for that i hate angular, that i dont know about existenceof plugins and i waste time. thank you i guess it will solve my problems.

Comment: not hard to do a google search

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `owlcarousel` on the specific element which you get from the directive's `link` function.

```js
link: function(scope, element) {
  scope.$watch('bannerOptions', function() {
    element.owlCarousel({
      loop: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      autoPlay: true,
      pagination: false,
      items: 1
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: link: function(scope, element) {
                element.children().owlCarousel({
                    loop: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    pagination: false,
                    items: 1
                });
            } this is not working.

Comment: Why `children`? Can you show me the html content of these `div`s?

Comment: <div data-interval="vm.options.myInterval" class="owl-carousel">

    <div data-ng-repeat="banner in vm.banners track by $index" data-index="$index">
...
</div>

Comment: Maybe just use an existing directive such as https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel